# Xcode - Communication Failed

Tags: xcode, xcode6

When I'm trying to submit a build to AppStore I'm get "Communication Failed" error:
"An error occurred while communicating with the Member Center. Please file a bug and include a copy of your System log from Console.app:
http://bugreporter.apple.com/."

[image]

How to fix it? I'm using Xcode 6.3.2 (6D2105)

Comment: [System status](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/) says it's all good now, but [member center](developer.apple.com/membercenter) still says "We'll be back soon."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just log in to Member Center and see: "We'll be back soon."

So I think it's temporary.